# Give my user and wwwdata group full permission to folder and its content

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, apache2, amazon-ec2

I'd like to know if it's possible to give a folder ("tmp") full (rwx) permission to my user ("ubuntu") and www-data group.

I tried with:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www/wondermap/html/tmp
sudo find /var/www/wondermap/html/tmp -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wondermap/html/tmp -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

and doing ls -ld tmp/ I can now see:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu www-data 4096 Jan  4 23:04 tmp/
```

which I think it's right. Is it?

I am asking because my application which should write files in tmp folder with www-data user that is in www-data group is not working on my production server, while on my dev machine it's fine and I just thought this could be a permission issue.

Also, maybe this could be related: my production server is an Amazon AWS ec2 if that matters.

**EDIT**

I restarted my server after @GeorgeUdosen suggestion, but unfortunately that did not solve the problem.

So let me explain my issue (feel free to vote for moving it if you think it's not askubuntu related anymore)...

I have a website where a Download button triggers a PHP on my AWS ec2. When clicked, the PHP is creating a folder in tmp, creating files in this folder, zip the folder with the files and send it to the client. The client using JS saves the zipped file and force the browser to download it.

Everything is fine from my dev machine, so I copied the code to my production server (the ec2). When clicking the download button in the production website, the browser download a zipped file, but it is invalid and if I open it with gedit I can see the PHP source code instead of the desired generated files (some CSVs).

Now, I thought it was a permission issue because I don't see the supposed generated folders files and zip in the tmp folder in the ec2, that's why I asked this question.

However, if permissions are right, I should consider to search the cause of the problem somewhere else.

I did ask about inbound and outbound rules on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/948326/invalid-file-for-download-generated-with-php-and-www-data-user) not to spam my problem but to get an idea if these Amazon setup rules could be the problem.

**SOLUTION**

I feel so stupid... it turns out PHP was not installed on my server...

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: It might be a permission issue but we need to see error messages to know. Yes your permissions are right but remember to start the server to apply the changes!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks for the feedback. Do you mean I have to restart the server whenever I make some permission change to a folder?

Comment: Yes, your server has to reload its configuration files to pick those changes!

Comment: I rebooted the server but unfortunately that did not solve my issue. Will try to explain my error better edinting my question (unfortunately, i son't know what is causing the problem so even explaining everything is a bit complicated for me...)

Comment: Please look in your server logs!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I saw 2 interesting thing in /var/log/apache2/error.log: 1) there was a permission error in another folder where my PHP (see edited answer) was getting data, that is now fixed (I can confirm it because I gave permission to www-data, restart the server and don't see the same error in the log). 2) Another error which brings me to a network issue (maybe?): `[Wed Jan 09 21:41:54.481915 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 993:tid 140129768896256] (101)Network is unreachable: [client 31.159.53.128:28313] AH01974:$` I confirm that is the IP from which I am trying to download the data in the server.